# Simplest way to wrap custom authentication into Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

Suppose I have simple bean, which can authenticate user by password and also know roles of any specified user:

```
interface MyBeanInterface {
    boolean check(String username, String password);
    List<String> roles(String username);
}
```

What is the simplest way to plug this functionality into Spring web application with basic HTTP security?

Simultaneously, I would like to annotate my controllers and service methods with `@Secured` annotation only. No any dot-separated predicates [like here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests), please.

I can't break through that numerous "populators", "managers", "adapters" and other "configurers" in Spring Security API...

**UPDATE**

I wrote:

1) A `Greeting` class to return from controller

2) A `GreetingController` class to serve web requests `/greeting1` and `/greeting2`. I annotated first method with `@Secured({"USER", "ADMIN"})` and the second with `@Secured({"ADMIN"})`.

3) I wrote `MyAuthService` where I authenticated two user with different level of access.

4) I wrote `AuthenticationProviderEx` where implemented `authenticate()` method with calling `MyAuthService` bean.

5) I wrote `SecurityConfig` bean with `configure()` returning my provider.

The code is [here in commit fdc2466](https://github.com/dims12/spring-simple-auth-wrapper/tree/fdc246699f8b933d1ba55a026a2f4cd895058c26). In this state it does not asking authentication at all.

**UPDATE 2**

I have added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` to `SecurityConfig` class and it started to ask username and password, but, unfortunately, returns error `403` on any request.

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom authentication provider wrapper around your interface, something like:

```
@Component("customAuthenticationProvider")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private MyBeanInterface myInterface;

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        if (!myInterface.check(username, password)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad username or password.");
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String role : myInterface.roles(username)) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.equals(clazz);
    }

}
```

And use it in your security config, with XML:

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

**Update:** Also works with java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    /* rest of security config here */
}
```

The rest is pretty normal stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Add a java config like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  
    @Autowired YourAuthFilter youfilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(yourfilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

and `YourAuthFilter` would be like this:

```
@Component
public class YourAuthFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Autowired private MyBeanInterface myBeanInterface;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // extract http basic tokens
        // use your myBeanInterface to authenticate
        // if it was successful, set Authentication 
        // by using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(...)
        // otherwise, do whatever suits your application needs
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

holmis83 approach is much better but if you want to use it in Java Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you use roles?

Comment: create `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` after successful authentication